# How to create Android App Widget from PreferenceActivity as configuration activity

Tags: android, android-widget, preferenceactivity

I have an app which basically consists of a widget. I need to configure this widget, that is the reason why I use a configuration activity. I thought it would be very simple to use a `PreferenceActivity` as the configuration activity.

I already googled up some things but at some point I stuck. All tutorials say, that I need to do this when configuration is finished:

```
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
```

Now, this works fine when simply copied for non-sense in the `onCreate()` method of the `PreferenceActivity`. Since it is a `PreferenceActivity`, I have nothing like a button, which says "Configuration finished" and I even can not add such a button in a `PreferenceActivity`. When the above code is added to the `onDestroy()` method it seems like it is too late because the widget is not created eventually. But `onDestroy()` or `onStop()` is the only place where the configuration is finished because the user pressed the Android back button.

What is a reasonable solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `onBackPressed()` :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();

}
```

Comment: Meanwhile I get to the same conclusion by myself but had no time to update it here. Thanks for your suggestion. It is the correct answer for me